# FirestoreSwift @DocumentID fails to compile in Xcode 11

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the `FirebaseFirestoreSwift` module in my Xcode 11 project but can't compile the following struct.  I get the error:

> Property type 'String' does not match that of the 'wrappedValue' property of its wrapper type 'DocumentID'

```
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct CustomerLocation: Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String  // <- error is here
    let contactEmail: String
    let contactName: String
    let contactPhoneNumber: String
    let serviceContactEmail: String
}
```

I am doing a simple fetch and document decode like so:

```
func fetchCustomerLocation(path: String) {
   firestore.document(path).getDocument{ (document, error) in
      guard error == nil, let document = document, document.exists else {
         print("Error retrieving customer location document. \(error!.localizedDescription)")
         return
      }

      do {
         let result = try document.data(as: CustomerLocation.self)
         print(result!)
      }
      catch let error {
         print("Error retrieving parsing location document. \(error.localizedDescription)")
      }
  }
}
```

I'd prefer not to pass in a `[String: Any]` into an `init`.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using optionals, such as `@DocumentID var id: String?`

Comment: What are you expecting that `@DocumentID` to do? Could you link to documentation?

Comment: I don't think `@DocumentID` has anything to do with any Firebase products. While there's an answer, it's unclear with `@DocumentID` is - can we have more info as to what that's in regard to as an internet search revealed nothing.

Comment: Hi @Jay, I ended up in the Firebase iOS SDK GitHub repo reading though the issues to understand `@DocumentID`

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Firestore/Swift/Source/Codable/DocumentID.swift

Answer (score 1):

The `@DocumentID` property wrapper does have an optional `init` as:

```
public struct DocumentID<Value: DocumentIDWrappable & Codable & Equatable>:
    DocumentIDProtocol, Codable, Equatable {
    var value: Value?

    public init(wrappedValue value: Value?) {
      self.value = value
    }

    ...
```

So the suggestion from **sllopis** resolved my issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("entidades").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let querySnapshot = querySnapshot else { return }
    self.entidades = querySnapshot.documents.compactMap { document -> Entidad? in 
        try? document.data(as: Entidad.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.